# Change script data-location for a <script> inside HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to modify one tag using javascript. I have a textbox to introduce a postcode and a button to find car parks near the position. The HTML tag is the following:

```
<script src="http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js" data-Location="http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/ST84JF/" data-options="l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2" data-size="750:400" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have two questions:

1. Can I modify the data-location to add the text write inside the textbox to search in that location?
2. Can I activate the script only when the button is clicked using javascript or jquery? The main problem here is that the  should be inside the HTML code and I don't know how to put it inside the javascript file.

Code updated:

```
function find(){
    $("script[id=script_map]").remove()
    var search = document.getElementById('box_txt').value ;
    $("<script />", {
        "src":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js",
        "data-location":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/" + search,
        "data-options":"l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
        "data-size":"750:400",
        "id":"script_map",
        "type":"text/javascript"
    }).appendTo("#divId")
}
```

Comment: _"Can I modify the data-location to add the text write inside the textbox to search in that location?"_ Not certain interpret this portion of Question correctly ? How would `data-location` attribute be modified ?

Comment: At the end of the `data-location` I would like to put the postcode introduced in the textbox using javascript. But the problem is that loading the script in the HTML, I don't know how to reload the script when I click in the button to search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try modifying `data-location` of `script` element before appending `script` element to `body` at `click` event of `button` element . Could alternatively use `$.getScript()` to retrieve `script` from external source

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var val = $("input").val();
  // Can I activate the script only when the button is clicked
  $("<script />", {
    "src":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/js/embeds/mapView.js",
    // Can I modify the data-location to add the text write inside the textbox
    // to search in that location?
    "data-location":"http://en.parkopedia.co.uk/parking/ST84JF/" + val,
    "data-options":"l=0&tc=0&zc=1&country=UK&ts[]=4&ts[]=3&ts[]=2",
    "data-size":"750:400",
    "type":"text/javascript"
  }).appendTo("body") 
})
```

Comment: Never knew you could dynamically append script tags after page load and them actually execute! Learn something new every day

Comment: However; is this wise to keep appending a new instance of the script each time the search parameters are changed with no way of ending whatever may be in progress by the first instance?

Comment: This solution works fine for me, the problem is that you have to control the number of clicks, because when you click on the button once works fine, but if you click again it shows two windows, so the first one should be removed

Comment: @UKAndroid Could add an `id` to `script` element , remove `script id="id"` before creating, appending new `script` to page

Comment: I've been searching about that and I think that a script cannot be removed. Maybe if I place it inside an iframe can be done. The main problem is that the script should be reloaded each time that I click on the button and your method works, but show a different windows each time.

Comment: @UKAndroid _"been searching about that and I think that a script cannot be removed"_ ? Link to what found where allude to `script` element not being able to be removed ? `script` element should be able to be removed with `$("script[id=id]").remove()` .  _"but show a different windows each time."_ Is expected result to show different `window` each time button is clicked?, or not show different window each time `button` clicked ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 I found that is loaded in memory and cannot be removed, but I'm going to try to put inside a `div` and then clear all the `div` content before load the script again. How can I `appendTo`the script inside a div with id, because this does not work: .appendTo("#DivId")

Answer (score 0):

Yes the data-location is simply a custom attribute i believe so just use

```
document.getElementById("SCRIPTTAGID").setAttribute("data-location", "newValue");
```

As far as activating the script to execute when a button is pressed you will need to encapse it in a function then call the function in the onClick event of the button.

Comment: Maybe that works, but I don't know how to reload the script after press the button and change those attributes. I'm going to find how to do this to test your point.

Comment: The best way would be to encapse the entire script into a function then call that function to start/restart the script